# When TEXT is SOMETHING then do THAT - Unity 2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I wanted to do the thing, when Text equals "Cherries: 12" then do `GameJolt.API.Trophies.Unlock(******);`

The problem is, when I do this:

```
if(Text.Equals = "Cherries: 12")
        {
            GameJolt.API.Trophies.Unlock(******);
        }
```

It says `Cannot assign to 'Equals' because it is a 'method group'`
Also, I'm new to programming, so if I did anything wrong here, please inform me!

Can someone help me please?

Comment: As the error says, `Equals` is a method, not a property. So it should be invoked like `Text.Equals("Cherries: 12")`. Second, if you compare two strings, use `==`, not the assignment operator `=`. Example: `if (someVariable == "A")`.

Answer (score 1):

What type is `Text`? Is it of type `UnityEngine.UI.Text`? Or is it of type `string`? The reason you are getting the error `Cannot assign to 'Equals' because it is a 'method group'` is because you are calling the method `Equals` and attempting to assign the value "Cherries: 12" to it.

Instead of using the assignment operator `=`, you want to use a comparison operator `==`. It will compare to values. However, as you are already using `Equals`, you do not need any sort of comparison, you can simply pass in the value to the method.

If your `Text` is a UI object, the code should look like:

```
if(Text.text.Equals("Cherries: 12"))
{
    GameJolt.API.Trophies.Unlock(******);
}
```

However, if the `Text` is a string object, the code should look like:

```
if(Text.Equals("Cherries: 12"))
{
    GameJolt.API.Trophies.Unlock(******);
}
```

Alternatively, you can use the comparison operator without needing to use the `Equals` method.

```
if(Text == "Cherries: 12")
{
    GameJolt.API.Trophies.Unlock(******);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Equals is a function so you should do `Text.Equals("Cherries: 12")` instead, or `Text =="Cherries: 12 "`

This could help you to understand better the operators, so you could understand better what they do and how to use them
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_operators.htm